# How do we measure Time period of a SHM without mathematically calculating ? Consecutive passage through mean position or extreme postion?

Tags: experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator

(1)In measuring time period of a pendulum, it is advised to measure the time between consecutive passage through the mean position in the same direction. This is said to result in better accuracy than measuring time between consecutive passage through an extreme position.

EXPLANATION:  The speed near the extreme position is near zero and the decision by the observer that the bob has reached the extreme position may have some error due to slow movement. But the bob crosses the mean position with maximum speed so there is no hesitation in deciding that the bob has crossed the mean position and hence better accuracy(this was what i found when i googled it).

(2)The time period of a particle in simple harmonic motion is equal to the time between consecutive appearances of the particle at a particular point in its motion. This point is ANS: At the extreme position because the particle is in the same phase at the consecutive appearance.

Both the things look completely different. Which is correct OR are they both correct OR Is it the way i am thinking wrong ?. I don't understand it. Can anyone please explain it to me.

Comment: I would advise measuring the time for 20 return trips to an extreme position, then dividing by 20 to arrive at the period.  The period is not affected by the decreasing amplitude of the pendulum as it swings, and dividing the total time by 20 also divides the uncertainty in the measurement by 20.

Answer (score 1):

Consecutive appearances at any given point in the cycle will all have the same phase. You don't need zero phase angle, just a constant one.

The phase angle is changing at a constant rate, but the only way to determine it is to measure the distance and time together and calculate it from that. So we are back to measuring time accurately. This is best done in the centre.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any position in the pendulum cycle to measure its period, but there are good reasons why using the mean position is likely to give you a more accurate answer than using an extreme position.

However, note that if you are timing the period by measuring the interval between appearances of the bob at its mean position, then it must be going through the mean position in the same direction each time. If you just measure the interval between consecutive appearances at the mean position, then this is only half of the full period.

Another way to improve accuracy is to measure the time taken for a number of cycles - say ten - and then divide this time by the number of cycles to find the average period. This reduces the impact of any error in timing because it averages it out across multiple cycles.